# Link in sticky footer not clickable in Firefox and Chrome

Tags: html, css, firefox, webkit

I am using a sticky footer like described in:

- [How do you get the footer to stay at the bottom of a Web page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42294/how-do-you-get-the-footer-to-stay-at-the-bottom-of-a-web-page)
- http://ryanfait.com/resources/footer-stick-to-bottom-of-page/

I have a paragraph with a link that I want to be at the bottom of the page, so I put it in .footer.

The problem is that the link is not clickable in Firefox 3.5.2 and Chrome, it is behind .push. It does work in IE7 and IE8 but I guess that doesn´t say much.

I have toyed around with z-indexes but that does not work. By the way, I need the position:relative in #page to position some stuff inside that div.

**Is there a way to make a link in .footer clickable in all browsers?**

The relevant parts of the code:

**css**

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}
#page {
    width: 962px;
    text-align: left;
    min-height: 100%;
    /* sticky footer part */
    height: auto !important;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto -90px;
    /* end sticky footer */
    position: relative;
}
/* sticky footer part */
.push, .footer {
    height: 90px;
}
.push {
}
.footer {
    background: #181f18 url(../images/background-top.png) no-repeat center bottom;
}
```

**html**

```
<div id="page">
  <div id="wrapper">
    <div id="contents">bla bla</div>
  </div>
  <div id="footer">bla bla</div>
  <div class="push"></div>
</div>
<div class="footer">
    <p><a href="http://www.some-site.com/">Some Text</a></p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Solved it, adding a postion:relative and z-indexes did it:

```
.push, .footer {
    height: 90px;
    position: relative;
}
.push {
    z-index: 9000;
    position: relative;
}
.footer {
    background: #181f18 url(../images/background-top.png) no-repeat center bottom;
    z-index: 9999;
    position: relative;
}
```

Comment: To be cross browser compatible the push and footer classes also need to be position relative for the z-index to be recognized.

Comment: Please update your answer with Austin's comment. It really saved me a lot of time.

Answer (score 1):

I had similar problem in webkit browsers. Setting the z-index or position didn't solve the problem but after I set -webkit-transform:translate(0,0); the button is clickable again.

Answer (score 0):

Correct me if I'm wrong but I think you should add a negative value for z-index which pushes it back enabling the link button.

This worked for me

```
.footer, .push {
    height: 4em;
    position: relative;
    width: 90%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    z-index: -9000;
}
```